# Using the Scanner class, how could I keep a count of the number of Delimiter occurrences since the start of a new line?

Tags: java, csv, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I am new to Java and I am trying to write a program for finding a specific string value in CSV documents that use a pipe ( | ) as the delimiter (only using core Java, so no CSVreader library). I need to find a specific string "Employee Name" in the CSV docs, but since they are inconsistently formatted, I want the program to essentially use the searched string("Employee Name") as the column header and return all of the values under it, until it reaches the null value at the end of the list (the number of elements that would be in said column are unknown).

I was planning on using the Scanner class with a series of loops to keep track of the number of Delimiter occurrences per line (that is, restarting the count after every linebreak) so that I could use the relative location of the searched string to retrieve the values under it that would be a part of it as a "column". (So if there were 3 Delimiters before "Employee Name" was matched on line 4, the program would return the values of the field that is 3 Delimiters in for Line 5, Line 6, Line 7, etc until it hits a null value in one of the lines.

Sidenote: I am trying to allow for the search term to permit Whitespaces (such as in the case of "Employee Name", so I have been using the custom Delimiter:

scanner.UseDelimiter("[|\r\n]")

If this regex isn't correct for the task I am trying to accomplish, please let me know.

I would sincerely appreciate any suggestions or guidance in solving this.

Comment: "CSV documents that use a pipe ( | ) as the delimiter"...So, not a CSV?

Comment: Welcome to Java! From your comment it sounds like you've put quite a bit of thought into how you're going to solve the problem, but not attempted anything yet. The best thing you can do is get coding and see how you get on, if you get errors or get stuck then post the error with as much relevant information as you can and someonebody will answer. Have fun!